# Create an automaton with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I want to create this automaton with LaTeX:

[image: screenshot]

The code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
semithick]
\node[initial,state] (A) {$1$} ;
\node[state,accepting] (B) [right of=A] {$2$};
\node[state,accepting] (C) [below of=A] {$3$};

\path (A) edge node  {a} (B)
edge node {b} (C)

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have you looked at the `tikz/pgf` manual? see section 24, pg 258

Comment: Take a look at the [tag:automata] tag.

Comment: I succeed to create my automaton except the two label return(a) ,return(b).How can I add the thwo labels in my automaton ?

Comment: @user29570 you can add your current code as an edit to your question.

Comment: @user29570 [Edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/110405/edit) your question providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), otherwise, we hardly can help you. For TikZ you can use the `label` option: `\node[<options>, label=below right:return(b)] {3};`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ok I will send my code..

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I want to add this label return(OP-AR,PLUS) using this \node[state,accepting] [label=below right:return(OP-AR,PLUS)](4) [above right of=3] {$4$}; I encountered a error !!

Comment: @user29570 As usual, you need to enclose any `,` that should not split by option spliter in `{ }`. For example: `\node[state,accepting] [label=below right:{return(OP-AR,PLUS)}](4) [above right of=3] {$4$};`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto]
\node[state,initial] (q_0) {1};
\node[state, accepting, label = below right:return(a)] (q_1) at (3,0) {2};
\node[state, accepting, label = below right:return(b)] (q_2) at (1.5,-2) {3};

\path[->] (q_0) edge node[swap] {$b$} (q_2);
\path[->, bend left = 30] (q_0) edge node {$a$} (q_1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's how the output looks like:

[image: mwe_for_automaton.png]

Comment: `node[swap] {$b$}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you so much! I have now changed it as per your correction. :)

Answer (score 5):

Using [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) for automata diagrams

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{%
*+<2pc>[o][F-]{1} \ar@(ul,ul)[]^>>>{start} \ar@/^0pc/[r]^a \ar@/_1pc/[dr]^b
& *+<2pc>[o][F=]{2} \ar@{}[d]^<<<{return(a)}  \\
& *+<2pc>[o][F=]{3} \ar@{}[]^<<<{return(b)} }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.. how to place return (b) the right of the state 3?

Comment: @user29570 is [this position](http://i.imgur.com/NzXreY6.png) ok ?

Answer (score 5):

For completeness sake, time for an old school automata package: `vaucanson-g`! `:)`

Compile with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{vaucanson-g}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{VCPicture}{(0,-2)(2,2)}

\State[1]{(-2,2)}{STATEONE}
\FinalState[2]{(2,2)}{STATETWO}
\FinalState[3]{(0,0)}{STATETHREE}

\Initial{STATEONE}
\FinalR{ne}{STATETWO}{\text{return}(a)}
\FinalR{ne}{STATETHREE}{\text{return}(b)}

\LArcL{STATEONE}{STATETWO}{a}
\LArcR{STATEONE}{STATETHREE}{b}

\end{VCPicture}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Update, per OP request:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{vaucanson-g}

\begin{document}

\begin{VCPicture}{(0,-2)(2,2)}

\State[1]{(-2,2)}{STATEONE}
\FinalState[2]{(2,2)}{STATETWO}
\FinalState[3]{(0,0)}{STATETHREE}

\Initial{STATEONE}

\LArcL{STATEONE}{STATETWO}{a}
\LArcR{STATEONE}{STATETHREE}{b}

\rput(4,2){\LARGE return$(a)$}
\rput(2,0){\LARGE return$(b)$}

\end{VCPicture}

\end{document}
```

The new output:

[image: New output]

Comment: Thank you ..Is it possible to remove the arrows on the states 2 and 3?

Comment: @user29570: It's been a while since I used `vaucanson-g` for the last time, but since it's PSTricks under the hood, we can use `\rput` and inject our text in the position we want it to appear, as I did in my update. I'm used to see transducers with the output represented as an arrow, but of course this is a matter of personal taste. `:)`