# Create automata with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I failed to create this automata with LaTeX:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
\node[initial,state] (A) {$1$};
\node[state] (B) [right of=A] {$2$};
\node[state] (C) [right of=B] {$3$};
\path
(A) edge node {\t,\n,' '} (B)
(B) edge node {other} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error:

`(A) edge node {\t,\n,' '} (B)`

Comment: Did you try using TuLiP toolbox (used for formal synthesis) ? It has an automatic automaton creator in PDF format.

Comment: You need to escape the ``\``: `\textbackslash t, \textbackslash n,' '`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Incase @Qrrbrbirlbel comments resolved your problem. you have similar titled Q [Create an automaton with LaTeX marked as duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110405/15717)

Comment: thank you all ,so I must delete this post because it's deplicate ??

Comment: Hi,I Have a problem with another automata ,so I can create a new post or I must use this post ? thank you

Comment: @user29570 If its related you can proceed asking moderators at [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) to open or else make a new question with a title more descriptive of problem and context it is used. Don't forget to add MWE.